# Why is the class $[i^*i_*\mathcal{F}]$ not equal to $i^*i_*[\mathcal{F}]$ in K-theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, k-theory

Let $i:X\to Y$ be a closed embedding of smooth varieties and $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Then why is $i^*i_*[\mathcal{F}]\neq[\mathcal{F}]=[i^*i_*\mathcal{F}]$ in $K_0(X)$?

EDIT: the previous version of this question asked why $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\neq\mathcal{F}$ and included a proof that $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}$ until Roland helped me understand the question was wrongly formulated.

Comment: Where did you see that $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\neq\mathcal{F}$ ? The canonical map $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism on stalk. Indeed $(i^*i_*\mathcal{F})_x=(i_*\mathcal{F})_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,x}}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,x}}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathcal{F}_x$ since $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a quotient of $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ and $\mathcal{F}_x$ is an $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module.

Comment: In equivariant K-theory (say, p. 262 from Chriss and Guinzburg), I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Here is the statement in the stack project : http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01C1 (this is lemma 17.13.4)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the stacks project. Evidently, my question was not well formulated (I hadn't even included a tag to K theory).

Comment: So maybe you should write $[\mathcal{F}]$ for the class of $\mathcal{F}$ in $K_0(X)$ and I assume that every thing is smooth. Then your question is not why $[i^*i_*\mathcal{F}]\neq [\mathcal{F}]$ because these class are equal (the sheaves are isomorphic), but why $i^*i_*[\mathcal{F}]\neq [\mathcal{F}]$. Is this the right question ?

Comment: You are right. Give 2 minutes to edit again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counter-example, I hope it will show why the equality does not hold.

Let $X=0$ and $Y=\mathbb{A}^1$ as in your post. Let $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X=k$. Then $i_*\mathcal{F}$ is not a vector bundle, so we need to find a resolution by vector bundles. Here is one : 
$$ 0\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_Y\overset{\times t}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow i_*k\rightarrow 0$$

So $[i_* k]=i_*[k]=[\mathcal{O}_Y]-[\mathcal{O}_Y]=0$. Hence $i^*i_*[k]=0$.

Comment: Ok, technically I see the issue, do you have a short intuitive/geometric explanation for why a non locally sheaf like this skyscraper is trivial in the Grothendieck group (I mean, apart from the axiomatic requirement of the additive rule over SES's)? I can't think of it as a set of sections, so what kind of object is it?

Comment: @EvaristoCarriego The Grothendieck group of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is simply isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ via the rank. The thing is, a sheaf supported on a closed subscheme has rank 0.

Comment: But maybe, the best explanation is using other homology theory. In general, a map $i^*i_*$ in (co)homology is almost never an isomorphism since it changes the homological degree. Here the group $K_0$ is "kind of" $\bigoplus CH^n(X)$ (There is an isomorphism only with rational coefficients, but even then the maps $f^*$ and $f_*$ does not match so this is absolutely not a rigorous argument )